# Lognorm data fit with curve_fit python

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit a lognorm function to my set of data using curve_fit to find the mu, sigma and A of the lognorm function and using them to plot the best curve to dataset. But the plot is not really good. I;ve already looked some of the answers here in StackOverflow and tried somethings but it didn´t work either.

This is what I have so far.

```
import numpy as pd
from scipy.stats import lognorm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


#Dataset
x1 = np.asarray([12.5205 12.521  12.5215 12.522  12.5225 12.523  12.5235 12.524  12.5245
 12.525  12.5255 12.526  12.5265 12.527  12.5275 12.528  12.5285 12.529
 12.5295 12.53   12.5305 12.531  12.5315 12.532  12.5325 12.533  12.5335
 12.534  12.5345 12.535  12.5355 12.536  12.5365 12.537  12.5375 12.538
 12.5385 12.539  12.5395 12.54   12.5405 12.541  12.5415 12.542  12.5425
 12.543  12.5435 12.544  12.5445 12.545  12.5455 12.546  12.5465 12.547
 12.5475 12.548  12.5485 12.549  12.5495 12.55   12.5505 12.551  12.5515
 12.552  12.5525 12.553  12.5535 12.554  12.5545 12.555  12.5555 12.556
 12.5565 12.557  12.5575 12.558  12.5585 12.559  12.5595 12.56   12.5605
 12.561  12.5615 12.562  12.5625 12.563  12.5635 12.564  12.5645 12.565
 12.5655 12.566  12.5665 12.567  12.5675 12.568  12.5685 12.569  12.5695
 12.57   12.5705 12.571  12.5715 12.572  12.5725 12.573  12.5735 12.574
 12.5745 12.575  12.5755 12.576  12.5765 12.577  12.5775 12.578  12.5785
 12.579  12.5795 12.58   12.5805 12.581  12.5815 12.582  12.5825 12.583
 12.5835 12.584  12.5845 12.585  12.5855 12.586  12.5865 12.587  12.5875
 12.588  12.5885 12.589  12.5895 12.59   12.5905 12.591  12.5915 12.592
 12.5925 12.593  12.5935 12.594  12.5945 12.595  12.5955 12.596  12.5965
 12.597  12.5975 12.598  12.5985 12.599  12.5995 12.6    12.6005 12.601
 12.6015 12.602  12.6025 12.603  12.6035 12.604  12.6045 12.605  12.6055
 12.606  12.6065 12.607  12.6075 12.608  12.6085 12.609  12.6095 12.61
 12.6105 12.611  12.6115 12.612  12.6125 12.613  12.6135 12.614  12.6145
 12.615  12.6155 12.616  12.6165 12.617  12.6175 12.618  12.6185 12.619
 12.6195], dtype=np.float64)

y1 =  np.asarray([ 427.  440.  409.  423.  451.  423.  418.  406.  406.  456.  416.  427.
  384.  448.  450.  421.  400.  412.  427.  434.  416.  424.  392.  386.
  428.  428.  430.  434.  442.  421.  414.  418.  425.  418.  404.  409.
  413.  421.  438.  424.  435.  382.  432.  415.  468.  420.  406.  432.
  458.  402.  438.  430.  441.  425.  427.  414.  398.  396.  447.  415.
  384.  393.  438.  459.  431.  426.  422.  420.  406.  446.  432.  517.
  758. 1334. 2068. 3158. 4504. 5638. 6667. 7019. 7331. 7051. 6480. 5879.
 5385. 4631. 4135. 3769. 3237. 2983. 2782. 2636. 2474. 2437. 2351. 2277.
 2347. 2256. 2252. 2225. 2259. 2242. 2202. 2178. 2192. 2156. 2182. 2129.
 2184. 2196. 2111. 2194. 2122. 2121. 2042. 2116. 2128. 2092. 2132. 2041.
 2060. 2107. 2086. 2106. 1933. 1971. 1985. 2006. 1965. 2019. 1917. 1926.
 1924. 1951. 2018. 2045. 2000. 2040. 1977. 2020. 1996. 1986. 1958. 2048.
 1976. 1959. 2038. 1960. 2042. 2053. 1913. 1976. 2074. 2041. 1997. 2016.
 1962. 2050. 1922. 2049. 1985. 2015. 2068. 1975. 2020. 2039. 2057. 1976.
 2013. 1934. 1951. 2043. 1997. 1995. 2050. 1969. 1990. 2011. 2036. 2042.
 2051. 1979. 2011. 1982. 1982. 1994. 2014. 1986. 1990. 2011. 1986. 2027.
 2038. 1950. 2034. 1977. 2066. 1949. 2050.]], dtype=np.float64)

#Lognorm function
def lognorm_fit(x, mu, sigma, A):
    y_lognorm = (A/(sigma*x*np.sqrt(2*np.pi))) * np.exp(-1* ((np.log(x) - mu)**2/(2*sigma**2)))
    return y_lognorm

#Curve_fit
popt, pcov= curve_fit(lognorm_fit, x1, y1)
mu = popt[0]
sigma = popt[1]
A = popt[2]
print(mu)
print(sigma)
print(A)


ajuste = lognorm_fit(x1, mu, sigma, A)

#Plot Results
plt.plot(x1,y1, "ro")
plt.plot(x1, ajuste)
plt.show()
```

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFabM.png)

Answer (score 0):

The shape of the curve for the probability density function for the log normal distribution is :

[image]

Obviously the shape of a curve correctly fitting your data is different :

[image]

The most important is that the limit values (on "plateaux") are not equal for high x than for low x.

This shows that the log normal equation isn't convenient to model your experiment. It is not surprising that the blue curve represented on your graph is very far from the data points.

You should derive from the physical properties of the experiment a more realistic equation model to be introduced into your software instead of the actually implemented log normal equation.

IN ADDITION after some comments :

From purely mathematical viewpoint one can certainly find a lot of combination of functions fitting more or less correctly the data. An example is shown below. The drawback is that the equation model has no physical signifiance.

[image]

In this example the equation y(x) is made of the combination of two functions of logistic kind. The values of the parameters a, b, c, A, B, C given on the figure are rough values. No accurate non-linear regression has been carried out. Note that the values of the parameters c and C are critical and have to be computed with more accuracy.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm trying to find a function that would work better for my data. I already have a sum of different functions that works fine, but I'm trying new things. I did a normal test in my data and it doesn´t come from a normal distribuition. I'll keep working on experiment differents kind of functions, maybe another mix would work better. Thanks!

Comment: @Beatriz Nattrodt D'Avila. Certainly the data isn't taken out of the air. It comes from somewhere. If you can modelize the phenomena which are involved in the data generation you will get a convenient kind of function much better than any combination of arbitrary functions. For example see the addition at end of my main answer.